# Drupal 8 Blog Autoposting To Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn etc

Tags: 8, nodes

I'm deciding what technology to use to build a social website. One of the features I'd like is autoposting to Facebook, Twitter, Linkedin, Youtube etc from a blog.

Joomla has a component called easyblog - http://stackideas.com/easyblog. I was wondering if there is anything similar for Drupal?

Normally I build basic websites with Joomla and more complicated things with Drupal 7 but with 8 out would ideally like to have used that.

Kind regards and many thanks for your time it is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There's a framework of modules under development as part of a 'Social initiative'. See https://www.drupal.org/project/social_post

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I can see it's very much new as there's only twitter support (sandbox) but will keep an eye on developments.